# OutOfMemory issue loading several pictures

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have nine pictures that I want to load at the start of an activity, and I'm getting problems of OutOfMemory exceptions. At first I loaded them directly in the xml setting its src. So after getting java.lang.OutOfMemory I realized that maybe I needed to load the pictures more efficiently and I created this loop to be executed at the begining of the activity:

```
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        String background = "background"+(i+1);
        int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(background, "drawable", getPackageName());
        int idPicture = getResources().getIdentifier(background, "id", getPackageName());

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), idDrawable, options);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(idPicture);
        image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), idDrawable, options));
}
```

But I still have the same OutOfMemory issue, any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: load images asynchronously in background thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code.
Change this code

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), idDrawable, options);
```

to

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 4;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), idDrawable, options);
```

and remove this line

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, but without removing `options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;` because otherwise the image isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit of googeling and searching by yourself would lead you to that Android Developers HowTo

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html